# Estimating the adequate ADC resolution given a sensor resolution

Tags: adc, sensitivity

A force traducer has a resolution of 0.0625N. And the analog output sensitivity is 32N/V. So I calculate the voltage output resolution as 0.0625/32 which is around 2mV.

If this signal now is sampled by an ADC with an effective resolution of 0.5mV or 4mV what would be the benefits or disadvantages? What would be the advantage of going better ADC resolution or disadvantage going lower ADC resolution?

(I'm neglecting any other external noise)

Comment: Going towards lower resolution ADC can save you a lot of power. It depends on your application, really. Are you looking to capture the smallest (0.0625N) change in force ?

Comment: Yes I wonder how to choose the adequate ADC resolution for that change in force

Comment: @atmnt This sounds an awful lot like a hypothetical. Which means probably some homework essay to show how much you might remember from what's been presented to you, instead of a real project ahead. Your use of "resolution" and "sensitivity" also seem a bit misguided to me. For example, a transducer resolution specification without a bandwidth specification pretty much isn't useful. So the first thing we'd normally want to know is the datasheet for your transducer and the bandwidth you need. But I suspect this is all a hypothetical question and you are supposed to write a bit of an essay.

Comment: @jonk Not an homework or essay really. The thing I wonder(was a discussion with a friend) is a general question and  is easier to ask with an example fx: If the minimum variation(min step or call it resolution) of the analog input signal is lets say 10mV, what should be our ADC's resolution limit? Would 5mV ADC resolution suffice?(Im neglecting any other noise or assuming random noise is around 1mV)

Comment: @atmnt Questions can be simplified just so much. If over-simplified, all you get are nonsense answers to a problem not characterized, but instead caricatured. Like cartoon people are to real people. So answers lose meaning. Take your example and tell me what the *raw* resolution is and the inherent bandwidth limitations, or if you just mean the static (near DC) resolution. Then tell me how often you need a measurement. That will help some. Also, is the noise white? If white and if you are allowed to average, and if you want increased precision, then you get different answers than otherwise.

Comment: @jonk Im lacking some depth and knowledge in the topic and probably thats why Im not asking the correct questions. I read some papers but they were complicated involved so much maths statistics. I really want to learn first what I need to know as a big picture that's why I tried to simplify but probably neglected important points. Could you show me how I can approach this matter conceptually? I cannot link the bandwidth concept with my question either. If you would make your own example involving correct parameters and show the approach it would help I believe.

Comment: @jonk Basically there is a known measurable analog signal parameters and desired bandwidth. How to decide the adequate ADC resolution.